# Laravel Multiple Sites

Tags: php, laravel, configuration

I need to set up two sites running from the same codebase in Laravel 4.2, I have done this before but I need some slightly different requirements this time.

Some of the assets CSS, JS and images would be the same but some would need to be overridden, I am happy to just have two public folders, with all front end assets duplicated, but if there are other suggestions that could make it easier that would be great.

My other requirement is that I would like to add a new PSR include route for site 2 that could override classes from site 1, when necessary. So I could call class user as below, site 1 would call the first class, site 2 would call the second class.

app/models/user.php

app/models/site-2/user.php

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could set up both domains to use same Laravel project directory and then you could create [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) which would check for current domain name:

```
$currentDomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Then you may just check for domain and decide what routes, controllers, models, views to use right now. I think this approach will solve you needs.

Comment: I don't think this a great solution it would involve a lot of if else statements, when what I really want is a solution that adds a PSR route for one site, so it uses all the classes from the other site unless there is a class that overrides the functionality.

Comment: You can add domain check into autoload files and autoload only classes you want, but I don't think it's a good idea to handle autoload manually anyway (why to use framework then?).  If you're using same Laravel installation for two websites, 90%-99% of your classes (including vendor ones) will be the same. You will not get any significant perfomance gain here.